# How can I duplicate the given curl command as a jquery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl

I have the following example of a REST API call -

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" -X POST \
-F "images_file=@test.jpg" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api/v2/classify?version=2015-12-02"
```

I want to perform the above call as a standard ajax request. This is what I have so far -

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function(blob){
        var uploadData = new FormData();
        uploadData.append('images_file',blob);

        $.ajax('https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition-beta/api/v2/classify?version=2015-12-02', {
        method: "POST",
        data: uploadData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ODdlOTTZIeg==');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Upload success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Upload error');
            console.log(data);
        }

    })

    })
```

I get an error as -

```
"{"code":400,"error":"Could not classify. Verify that valid images were uploaded."}"
```

My hunch is that cURL's `-F image_results=@test.jpg` is not being simulated correctly in the above ajax call.

cropper.getCroppedCanvas() is a function call from cropperjs library.

Answer (score 0):

Use `formData` with `blob` like this:

```
formdata.append("myfile", myBlob, "filename.txt");
```

See [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

> When using the append() method it is possible to use the third optional parameter to pass a filename inside the Content-Disposition header that is sent to the server. When no filename is specified (or the parameter isn't supported), the name "blob" is used.

So, for your case:

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function(blob){

    var uploadData = new FormData();

    var filename = "your-file-name-with-suffix";
    uploadData.append('images_file',blob,filename);

    //$.ajax(...);
});
```